# Change row height in gridex janus

Tags: row, janus, gridex

how to change row height of a `gridex` in `janus` when the `gridex` is binded to a root table? as you can see there is no property on `gridex` for setting row size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in init method of the form that grid is in it you can write :    `grdMPANDFilters.RootTable.RowHeight = somenumber`

Comment: FYI: this appeared in the low quality posts queue because someone flagged it. Your answer appears plausible, so I presume it is because it is a code-only answer.